# Query a remote XML file from an Android App

Tags: android, xml, sax

I am developing an application that is required to retreive information from an XML file stored on a server.

I have written a parser class, using SAX, that reads in the data and pops it into an object which I can then access as required.

How would I go about querying the data, for instance searching for particular values and then only reading in the relevant elements. Server side, I can easily write an XQuery in order to return the required elements, however I am unsure how to do this from my application.

Is it possible to execute querys server side and then parse the resulting XML file?

I'm a little lost. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing on Android 2.2 or later, you can take advantage of the `javax.xml.xpath`'s functionality (introduced in API level 8).

If you are developing on Android 2.1 or earlier, the server side filter (as you suggested: xquery or xpath) would be the best, otherwise you should hard-filter your xml data, or wrap all of it into java Objects in a `List<?>`, and filter that list. Both ways are quite resource-eating.

In my opinion, if handling huge amount of data at once, but displaying just a small part of it, the server side filtering is better (even though it needs multiple http requests: on changing data sets this is unevitable anyway).

Comment: Is it possible to perform this server-side filter "live" - as in to perform an XQuery that returns record containing $x where $x is a string specified by the user in the application? Thanks.

Comment: You just need to add that `$x` as a parameter to your request. On server side you retrieve the parameter, based on that run the xquery, and write out the resulting xml data on the response. The rest is the same.